# Windows Backup folders have no previous versions?

Tags: windows-7, windows, backup

I started up Windows Backup on one of my drives recently. After a few weeks, I went to check on it.

When I right click on any folder in the drive, it says there are no previous versions for any folder. But if I right click on any of the files, the previous versions exist for the various backups it did.

Why am I not seeing any of the folders in these backups? When browsing the backup I see the folders, but that is the inconvenient way of looking at it, I think.

I've also noticed that every folder is read only to me, and no matter what I've done I can not get it out of read only mode. I've tried changing myself to my own owner on the drive, give me all permissions on specific folders, every time I remove read only, it always gets set back on.

Would this have an affect on the windows backup and why I cannot see the folders in previous versions?

Comment: Only the filesystem itself is permitted to write to a folder as detailed understanding of their structure is required. Users are permitted to traverse folders, to list their contents, to add files and folders to them, and so on. But not to write to them.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz That doesn't explain why windows backup is not listing them. Everything I've found so far indicates it should be listing the folders in previous versions, but it is not.

Comment: I agree. I'm just explaining why you have read only access to the folders. That's all that users ever get.